# How to perform variable calculations/addition within a String in LESS?

Tags: css, string, math, less

Is it possible to get "3" (instead of "1+2") as the final output in this snippet?

```
@a: 1;
@b: 2;
div {
  font-family: "@{a}+@{b}";
}
```

**Update**

The output should still be in a String:

```
font-family: "3";
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your example seams to be stripped down.
If you really want a string, use LESS string formatting.

Here is the doc: http://lesscss.org/functions/#string-functions--format

```
// LESS
@a: 1;
@b: 2;

div {
   font-family: %("%a", @a + @b);
}

// Generated output
div { font-family: "3" }
```

Comment: needs to be within a string

Comment: Nice, and [this tool](http://lesstester.com/) seems pretty useful for quick tests (shame you can't save them to link though). So I can upvote you as I know this does exactly what asked

Comment: @corgrath: Why don't you test it before you assume it doesn't work! If this isn't what you are asking, then you are really bad at asking questions

Comment: @musefan because all the answers I got from everyone else, removed it from being a String. I didn't know that the "%" returned a String. But I tested it now, thanks.

Answer (score -2):

You need only to make this:

```
@a: 1;
@b: 2;
div {
  font-family: @a + @b;
}
```

Note that there is an space between a and b variables

Comment: It needs to be in a string